# Filter numbers in a column that are available in a given set of numbers

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010. I have a set of numbers (say set A) that I want to select in filtering a bigger set (say set B) in another column.

Basically I am trying to find a way to replicate what in SQL queries is the `IN` operator:

```
Select * from TABLE_NAME tn where tn.userID in (234, 64, 26, 109);
```

I need to filter Excel rows with `userID` available in set B.

For a single number I have seen:

```
Filter on the Column > Click on the Filter > Go to Number Filters > Equals.
```

Comment: One way is to have a table with the values to filter on and a helper column, for filtering, that calculates whether the item in that row appears in the table. This [post of mine](http://yoursumbuddy.com/filter-pivot-tables-using-source-data-helper-columns/) shows some ways to do this.

Comment: @Silva : This works. But what if the set in bracket is more in number ? Can I pick this set from another column in excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label both lists the same and stack the values you wish to find above the list that contains some or all of those values. Then apply Data > Sort & Filter, Advanced as shown below on the left:

[image: SO20450459 example]

On the right is the result for the example in ColumnA on the left.